# C# add properties at runtime

Tags: c#

I've read few posts, and I'm still having troubles with adding properties to a class in runtime. It should be simple, because I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        String Template;
        String Term;
     }
```

During runtime, I have to add few attributes, like Phone, Email (it depends...). 
Could someone please explain me how to add these properties during class initialization?

Srecko

Comment: Why do you feel you need to add them at runtime? Why can't you add them to your class definition?

Comment: It is little bit complicated to explain, but I need to add them when I instantiate class. I cannot add them in class definition, because database table contains few fields, and I need to add few more during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think adding a property is the right thing to do here. 
The attributes like "Email" or "Phone" are just some additional pairs of a key and a value. You could use a `Dictionary`, but that would prevent you from using a key more than once (more than one email address for a contact for example). So you could just as well use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. Like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    String Template;
    String Term;
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Attributes { get; private set; }

    public MyClass() {
        Attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>();
    }

    public void AddAttribute(string key, string value) {
        Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
    }
}

// to be used like this: 
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
instance.AddAttribute("Email", "test@example.com");
instance.AddAttribute("Phone", "555-1234");
```

Comment: I think this should work. Actually, I need to add property only once. I have to try...

Comment: @Joksimovic If you are sure that you only need to add a property once, then a `Dictionary<string, string>` would be a good choice, too.

Comment: @Joksimovic With a Dictionary, you could also check if keys exist easier, like `someDictionary.ContainsKey("Email")`

Comment: Yes, that is true. I think that Dictionary should do the work. I am going to try this in next few minutes...

Comment: Thank you for your help! As you, and Carsten suggested, Dictionary did the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you have c# 4.0 you can use the Expando object.

for earlier versions of c#, the generally accepted way of doing this is to create a "property bag" i.e. a collection (or dictionary) of key value pairs

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = "test";
```

Comment: I have C# 4.0, but isn't Expando used for dinamically created objects? In this case, I have class already, and I want to add few more properties during initialization...

Comment: well, yes it is a dynamic object and I suppose you could create them dynamically. It pretty much is designed to work as a typed property bag, sounds like it would suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you could add an dictionary with for your Key/Value-Pairs.
Then if you add your attributes you just add `Key = Attributename`, `Value = YourValue` to the dictionary.
Reading is as easy - just get the Value to the `Key = Attributename` from your dictionary.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers. Your answer was helpful as well. Thank you!