# Binding to custom properties

Tags: silverlight, pagedcollectionview

A few hours ago I posted a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134264/c-sharp-add-properties-at-runtime). I asked about extending existing class with new properties. And, that was ok. I managed adding new propertis, but now I need to add GroupDescription to PagedCollectionView, based on dinamically added properties. This means that I have class

```
MyClass
{
    string _name;
    string _phone;
}
```

Now, I want dinamically to add new properties (JobTitle, Position), with generated values, and to define GroupDescriptions for JobTitle and Position. 
With mentioned implementation, i have

```
Dictionary<string, string> Attributes;
```

But, if I say

```
collection.AddGroupDescription(key);
```

it will group data based on Key - JobTitle, not by value.

Thank you,
Joksimovic

Comment: Why are you not using an observable collection instead of a dictionnary ?

Comment: What is the difference? I would probably still have key-value pair?

Comment: I am saying because if you incorporate the job title and position into the MyClass object you could have `collection.AddGroupDescription(jobtitle)` and it would be grouped as expected.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. That is what I want to do, but I didn't understand your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

So the standard way of achieving this is like the following

```
MyClass
{
    string _name;
    string _phone;
    string _jobTitle;
    string _position;
}


private ObservableCollection<MyClass> collection = //fetch from web service or something
PagedCollectionView pcv = new PagedCollectionView(collection);
pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("JobTitle"));
DataGrid.ItemsSource = pcv;
```

Comment: I see now... but, the problem is that _jobTitle and/or _position should be added dynamically. They are not in the class, they should be added during instantiating class. After that, everything should be like you described.

Comment: DataGrids do not support the binding to multiple sources. I think your best bet is to dynamically fill the 2 properties of the class when instantiating. This can be performed using foreach loop on the observable collection items and the display will be updated automatically.

Comment: OK, I will do that for now, but I think there must be different solution :) the point is, that I don't have these properties in the class, I want to add them during class initialization... anyway, thank you for you help.