# Add property an existing c# class during runtime

Tags: c#

I have a class like "Person"...

```
 public class Person  
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Id { get; set; }

    }
```

I have a DTO class like

```
 public class DTOAddress
    {
       public string City{ get; set; }
       public string Country{ get; set; }

    }
```

During runtime I need to get 'City' and 'Country' property in Person class. i.e
My expected result will be...

```
 public class Person  
        {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string City{ get; set; }
           public string Country{ get; set; }
        }
```

At runtime.

Comment: I have seen such link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134264/c-sharp-add-properties-at-runtime. But it does not meet my requirements.

Comment: I do not want to create new type. I want to extend existing type.

Comment: ExpandoObject and TypeBuilder does not meet my requirement.

Comment: Just so you know. This is extremely bad programming practice. A person does not necessarily have a `City` nor a `Country`.

Comment: What requirement are you trying to solve with this? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Trying to add properties at runtime is a very bad code smell at best (and impossible as worst - I won't say for sure it's definitely utterly impossible).

I recommend you rethink exactly what you're trying to achieve. If you know that it will always add `City` and `Country` to the class, why can't you just add them at compile-time? Telling us more about the problem in question could help us suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. Once a `class` is compiled you can't change it, it's done. But you can create a new class with new properties at runtime. There is a good information about that in MSDN:

- [Emitting Dynamic Methods and Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: This is more a comment !

Comment: @Shohel sorry it was the wrong link see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do not want to create new type using type builder

Answer (score 2):

You can try and use an `ExpandoObject` to add properties at run time. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx).

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Name = "Dude 1";
```

now the `expando` object contains a property `Name` with value `Dude 1`.